# Multiple SHELL Channels JSch java SSH

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

Basically, I have a java program that controls two different SSH connections using the JSch SSH library for Java.

I create my own class called SSHConnection that is a wrapper for the JSch libraries, and I initialize two copies by calling the constructor shown below:

> > public SSHConnection(String username,String password,String host, 
> >          String knownHosts, int portNumber) throws JSchException{
> >
> > ```
> >  JSch jsch = new JSch();
> >  jsch.setKnownHosts(knownHosts);
> >  this.session = jsch.getSession(username,host,portNumber);
> >  this.session.setPassword(password);
> >  this.session.connect();
> > ```
> >
> > }

Now, inside the SSHConnection class, in order to create the shell channel, I use this command:

> > shell = (ChannelShell)this.session.openChannel("shell");

However, I have found out that if I have already have a session open that is using the SHELL channel I get an error saying "Channel is not opened" (JSch Exception) when I try to open the first channel for the second session.

Is there a way  that I can open two Shell channels at once? Is this my problem, a JSch problem, or an SSH issue?

Edit::::

I can connect to the SSH server simultaneously from multiple terminals. For instance, in one terminal I can do...

ssh asofjpasf@myserver

and in another terminal I can do...
ssh opapaos@myserver

However, when I try to make a single program using JSch have the same behavior, it fails stating that the channel is not open when I try to open the second shell channel.

Comment: FYI, you can test running two sessions over the same transport with the command-line SSH client too -- see the ControlMaster, ControlPath and related options as documented at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to open two shell channels at once. I've seen embedded servers which disallow this, but an out-of-the-box OpenSSH server should have no problem with it.

By the way, for my own testing, I'm using clj-ssh (a Clojure wrapper for jsch, this implementation built against jsch 0.1.50):

```
(ns ssh-test.core
  (:use [clj-ssh.ssh]))

(defn test-conn []
  (let [agent (ssh-agent {})]
    (let [session (session agent "127.0.0.1" {:strict-host-key-checking :no})]
      (with-connection session
        (let [ch-a (shell-channel session)
              ch-b (shell-channel session)]
          [ch-a ch-b])))))
```

---

...or, using two separate sessions:

```
(defn test-conn []
  (let [agent (ssh-agent {})]
    (let [session-a (session agent "127.0.0.1" {:strict-host-key-checking :no})
          session-b (session agent "127.0.0.1" {:strict-host-key-checking :no})]
      (with-connection session-a
        (let [ch-a (shell-channel session-a)]
          (with-connection session-b
            (let [ch-b (shell-channel session-b)]
              [ch-a ch-b])))))))
```

Thus, this works correctly in either case.

Comment: Hmm. What happens if, instead of having one session, you do the same thing with two sessions? As in, one channel per session?

Comment: @vraiment I'm not sure I understand the context for your question. Are you asking whether embedded servers are going to disallow that? If so, it seems a very implementation-specific question -- if it's an in-process server, my guess would be yes; if it's a forking server, my guess would be no... but even then, that's assuming an ease-of-implementation decision rather than a policy decision.

Comment: I think my edit will clear things up, thanks for asking. Basically, I can run multiple SSH sessions, each with a SHELL channel open, just not within the same program.

Comment: @vraiment Updated to provide an example of that working as well.

Comment: ...by the way, the code I gave here is a complete reproducer. It wouldn't hurt for you to provide a SSCCE (see http://sscce.org/); although doing so in Java would be considerably more verbose, one can't diagnose a problem unless enough context is given to produce it.